# Promises returned data '<pending>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

my data which is fetched from youtube is using nodejs is -

```
    [ { title:
         'Dil  Zaffran Video Song | Rahat Fateh Ali Khan |  Ravi Shankar |  Kamal Chandra | Shivin | Palak',
        id: 'vChX3XZXqN4',
        view: '28652353' },
      { title:
         'Full Video: Akh Lad Jaave | Loveyatri | Aayush S|Warina H |Badshah, Tanishk Bagchi,Jubin N, ,Asees K',
        id: 'e_vl5aFXB4Q',
        view: '17328447' 
}]
```

Now I want to search 5 related videos to each video

my api

```
getVids(videosID)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)  //this is the data which I showed above
            result.sort((a,b) => b.view - a.view);
            return result;
        })
        .then(result => {

            return result.map(function(el) {
                // console.log(el);
                let o = Object.assign({}, el);

                o.relatedVideos = relatedVideos(el.id); //function is called below
                return o;
            });
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

and api to 5 related Videos is given below

```
function relatedVideos(videoId) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let urls = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?relatedToVideoId=' + videoId + '&key=' + API_KEY + '&part=snippet&type=video';
        request(urls, (err, result) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(result.body);
            const relatedVideos = [];
            data.items.forEach(related => {
                relatedVideos.push({
                    title: related.snippet.title
                });
                if(relatedVideos.length === 5){
                    resolve(relatedVideos);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

It is giving the output like

```
    [ { title:
         'Dil  Zaffran Video Song | Rahat Fateh Ali Khan |  Ravi Shankar |  Kamal Chandra | Shivin | Palak',
        id: 'vChX3XZXqN4',
        view: '28655496',
        relatedVideos: Promise { <pending> } },
      { title:
         'Full Video: Akh Lad Jaave | Loveyatri | Aayush S|Warina H |Badshah, Tanishk Bagchi,Jubin N, ,Asees K',
        id: 'e_vl5aFXB4Q',
        view: '17334681',
        relatedVideos: Promise { <pending> }
 }]
```

How to solve this `pending` problem or how to wait so it gets full data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you assign the promise returned by `relatedVideos()` to the property `relatedVideos`, you never actually wait for it to resolve. You need to await all of the promises before you proceed, this is most easily done with `Promise.all()`. Let's focus on this part of your code:

```
        return result.map(function(el) {
            // console.log(el);
            let o = Object.assign({}, el);

            o.relatedVideos = relatedVideos(el.id); //function is called below
            return o;
        });
```

What you need to do is to wait for each promise to resolve in order to get its resolved value before you assign it to the object. Then you also need to create a promise that doesn't resolve until all of those promises have resolved. This is what `Promise.all()` is for. Change the code mentioned above into this:

```
        return Promise.all(result.map(function(el) {
            // console.log(el);
            let o = Object.assign({}, el);

            return relatedVideos(el.id)
                .then(function(relatedVideo) {
                    o.relatedVideos = relatedVideo;
                    return o;
                });
        }));
```

Please note that ALL of the promises mapped to `Promise.all()` needs to resolve in order for the chain to continue with the next `then`. If even one of those promises rejects or don't resolve at all it will never continue. You have a condition for your `resolve()` call in the `relatedVideos()` function. This implies that in some cases a promise might end up never resolving. You should always resolve or reject a promise, perhaps `resolve(null)` would be appropriate in your case.

Comment: I think it should work, but it is not reaching to next `.then()`.

Comment: @Rupesh It should work if you copy my code exactly as I said. Your `resolve()` call in your `relatedVideos()` is conditional, if any of those promises don't resolve, it will never reach the next `then` in the chain. Make sure they all resolve, you really need to do something with the promise when your condition isn't met.

Comment: thanx, it works, there was the problem in the condition of 5 videos.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the promise has not been resolved, so your resolve function isn't being called. It would probably be a good idea to test this without the below conditional.

```
if(relatedVideos.length === 5){
    resolve(relatedVideos);
}
```

Comment: I checked This is not a problem.